# Using Spring @Pattern validation. What regular expression would let max 7 digits with up to 3 decimal places

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations

`^\d{0,7}(\.\d{0,3})?$` is not allowed due to Invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are defining a String like this:

```
String pattern = "^\d{0,7}(\.\d{0,3})?$";
```

The `\` inside the String needs to be escaped in Java.

Try this instead:

```
"^\\d{0,7}(\\.\\d{0,3})?$"
```